# AVPlayerViewcontroller play video url issues

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

## My Code:

This is our code

```
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strVideo];

    playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[playerController.player currentItem]];

        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;

        playerController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

        [self presentViewController:playerController animated:YES completion:nil];



        [playerController.player play];
```

}

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
{

       // [playerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"IT REACHED THE END");

}
```

Video is first play 2sec then replay from first to end.

Comment: is that code in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, a custom method?  If a custom method, is it a possibility that it is being called more than once? Is your notification being called? If you want help with your question you need to give some details on your issue.

Comment: It is custom method. no only once called - yes notification is called. -msu

Comment: is your notification being called once or multiple times? is your custom method called from viewDidLoad or from a button click?

Comment: notification is called once and custom method called webview tab action.-msu

Comment: So is the video playing the first 2 seconds repeatedly in a loop OR playing the first 2 seconds, then the rest of the video?

Comment: first 2 seconds play and repeat play full video-msu

Comment: have you tried putting `[playController.player play];` before presentViewController?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116099/discussion-between-ragu-and-msu-bulldog).